# Django unable to understand template html format

Tags: python, html, django, git

I am learning Django framework, I setup Django on my local host and successfully run my first app, and i downloaded some web app from git and then i tried to understand it but when i opened template html the format used their was completly different from original html format, so i just want to know what scripting, or language they are using to build html files, Here is a sample code

```
    {% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
{% if not is_popup %}
<a href="{{ recoverlist_url }}" class="recoverlink btn">
    <i class="icon-repeat"></i>&nbsp;
    {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|escape as name %}Recover deleted {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}</a>
{% endif %}
{{block.super}}
{% endblock %}
```

I am unable to get what {% %} doing here, Is it a scripting tag just like jsp or something else, If it is a scripting that what kind of script is it  ? because normally html files starts with

```
<head>
```

tag.

Comment: [Django template language docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) will definitely help.

Comment: It is only a part of a template, which extends `admin/change_list.html`. Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: If you're learning Django, did it occur to you to do the tutorial, where all this is explained?

Comment: can i use simple html instead of django template language ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a scripting tag just like jsp or something else

Yes.

> If it is a scripting that what kind of script is it ?

[Django Template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)

> because normally html files starts with `<head>` tag.

It's not HTML. It's a template language that render and outputs HTML.

I'd suggest you go through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/).